# adding more than 16 years in date showing error in php

Tags: php, date

I am just checking add years in php.

When I tried adding more than 16 years in current date, it is showing error.

```
$a1 = "2021-04-25 14:54:21";
$expirydate = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($a1. "+16 Years")); // Less than 16 years working
  echo $expirydate;
```

SHOWING **2037-04-25 23:59:59** And it is right.

**BUT**

```
$a1 = "2021-04-25 14:54:21";
$expirydate = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($a1. "+17 Years")); // Adding More than 16 Years showing error
  echo $expirydate;
```

SHOWING **1970-01-01 23:59:59**

Is there any max limit in php ?

Comment: It works correctly on my machine (PHP 8.0.3). Is your PHP version up-to-date?

Comment: php 7.3 I am using... can you try and check 20 years or onwards on your server ? just to check max limit...